# Filter out array values that result in errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I have 2 data structures. For simplicity lets suppose they are both 1 dimensional arrays. Assuming all functions are defined correctly, I want to do something like

```
Array1.delete_if(Array2.find(element in array 1) results in error)
```

I have no idea how to approach this. I've tried rescue statements and the such but I still end up with errors. Is there an efficient and easy way to filter out elements in an array based on if a method call results in an error?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `results in error` stuff supposed to mean? If `find` fails? What is an error in this context? Is it an exception or a specific type of return value?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear- I mean exceptions. Specifically I am experiencing NoMethodErrors but in general any exception that would be raised should be filtered out of the list. 


The find method is resulting in exceptions being raised- I want the exceptions, aka "elements that cannot be properly found", to be filtered out.

Comment: What does it mean to "filter out exceptions"?

Comment: To be even more clear: the NoMethodError is not due to the find method but because of the way I am calling the elements within the find method- which results in exceptions if invalid data is passed through.

Comment: @ndn I mean elements that result in exceptions be filtered out ..

Comment: But when does an element "result in exception"? Elements are just some objects, you have to do something with them so they would cause an exception. What is that something?

Comment: @ndn Best example I can give that is clear, at least to me, is if elements have a name attribute. I call the method find through `find(element.name)` which results in an exception if the element does not have a name.

Comment: @AdamS, then finding the element doesn't cause an exception, it's getting it's name that does. You can check with `element.respond_to?(:name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this, then:

```
array1.delete_if do |e|
  array2.find(e) and false

rescue
  true
end
```

Where that will remove anything that causes an exception when calling `find`.

Comment: How can something result in an exception when calling `find` (assuming `array2` is indeed an array)?

Comment: Why not `keep_if` or `select!`  instead? Control flow `and` just seems so out of place here. even `not(array2.find(e))` seems cleaner.

Comment: @engineersmnky Both of those are valid alternatives, but I'm just using what the original question had to keep the changes as modest as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to filter elements would be:

```
first_array - second_array
```

If you want to raise an error if you find any element from one in another:

```
raise 'error' unless (first_array & second_array).empty?
```

---

Last attempt:

```
first_array.select { |element| condition_with_second_array(element) rescue false }
```